# clearing out the browser data unregisters the service worker and installed pwa's dont work?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Hello every one i have observed that when i clear out the browser data the service worker gets unregistered and if after that i go offline or disconnect internet the installed progressive web app doesn't work anymore and gives the site can't be reached error. Is there any workaround to this issue how can one gracefully handle it because according to my understanding the service worker isn't in charge anymore so how to get around the site cant be reached problem where a user installs a progressive web app and then clears out the browser data and disconnects from the internet and then launch the pwa?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

If a user deletes the site data, then that includes the service worker.

They have to revisit the site to reinstall it.